# $\mathfrak{q} \notin \operatorname{Supp} \mathfrak{q}$ means some elememt vanishing on $\operatorname{Supp} \mathfrak{q}$ but not $\mathfrak{q}$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Here $\mathfrak{q}$ is some prime ideal of a commutative ring $B$, and $\operatorname{Supp} \mathfrak{q}$ is the support of $\mathfrak{q}$, treating it as a $B$-module:

$$
\operatorname{Supp} \mathfrak{q} := \{\mathfrak{p} \in \operatorname{Spec} B: \mathfrak{q}_\mathfrak{p} \neq \{0\}\}
$$
, i.e., those prime ideals of $B$ contaning non-zero germs.

From the hypothesis $\mathfrak{q} \notin \operatorname{Supp} \mathfrak{q}$, how can we conclude that there is an element $b$ of $B$ that vanishes on $\operatorname{Supp} \mathfrak{q}$ but doesn't vanish at $\mathfrak{q}$, i.e., $b$ lies in all prime ideals of $ \operatorname{Supp} \mathfrak{q}$, but not in $\mathfrak{q}$?

It's one step in the proof of [Vakil's FOAG, Page 187, Proposition 6.5.21](http://math.stanford.edu/%7Evakil/216blog/FOAGdec3122public.pdf). It seems easy but I cannot see how it holds. The best I got, from definition of support, is that

- $\mathfrak{q} \notin \operatorname{Supp} \mathfrak{q}$ means $\mathfrak{q}_\mathfrak{q} = \{0\}$. Hence for any $a/b$, with $a\in \mathfrak{q}, b \notin \mathfrak{q}$, there is some $c \notin \mathfrak{q}$, such that $ac =0$. Equivalently, for any $a \in \mathfrak{q}$, there is some $c \notin \mathfrak{q}$, such that $ac = 0$.
- It holds trivially if $\operatorname{Supp} \mathfrak{q}$ is empty. In this case all elements in $B$ vanish on $\operatorname{Supp} \mathfrak{q} = \varnothing$.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is $B$ Noetherian or completely arbitrary?

Comment: @Aphelli That's my second confusion if $B$ should be assumed Noetherian or not. The text does not say it's Noetherian explicitly. But another argument following this has to require $B$ Notherian. Any hints for proving this with assuming $B$ Noetherian?

Comment: Hint: if furthermore $B$ is Noetherian, then there is some $c \notin \mathfrak{q}$ such that $c\mathfrak{q}=0$…

Comment: Got it now, it should be enough for me with the case $B$ Noetherian. Thank you very much @Aphelli

Answer (score 1):

With Aphelli's hint, for the case $B$ Noetherian (should be enough for me), the detail is:

Since $B$ is Noetherian, $\mathfrak{q}$ is finitely generated. Let $\{a_1, \ldots, a_n\}$ be a generator set for $\mathfrak{q}$. Then by $\mathfrak{q} \notin \operatorname{Supp} \mathfrak{q}$, for each $i$, there is some $c_i \notin \mathfrak{q}$ such that $a_ic_i = 0$.
Take $b = c_1 c_2\ldots c_n$, then $b \notin \mathfrak{q}$ and for all $a \in \mathfrak{q}$, $ba = 0$.

$b$ vanishes on every point of $\operatorname{Supp} \mathfrak{q}$: suppose $b \notin \mathfrak{p}$. Then $\mathfrak{q}_\mathfrak{p} = \{0\}$ since for all $a \in \mathfrak{q}$, $ba = 0$. And hence $\mathfrak{p} \notin \operatorname{Supp} \mathfrak{q}$.